# FontForge: How to do autoWidthing and autoKerning for glyphs

Tags: python-2.7, width, kerning, fontforge

So far I have been able to insert glyphs in their appropriate places through fontforge scripting, but my problem now is that when I insert lets say the letter 'A' in its corresponding place, I should also emphasize the **Width** of this glyph, I can compute the width from the svg file but since the pictures are coming in different sizes it not reliable. I was wondering whether fontforge can guess the appropriate width for each glyph automatically. If yes! please provide some example.
The same problem applies for computing kerning between each two glyphs.

In [this link](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge.github.io/blob/master/en-US/documentation/reference/autowidth.md), I have read some stuff about autoWidth and autoKerning but couldn't make them work properly.